# How to make an edge mask without ambient occlusion in EEVEE

Tags: materials, geometry-nodes, shader-nodes

Is it possible to make an edge mask without turning on ambient occlusion in EEVEE? I've tried using geometry nodes too, but since it is based on the geometry, I'd have to do a lot of subsurfs to get a high-quality result.
Thank you!

Comment: No, it's not possible.  Shaders operate only on sample (fragment) data.  They do not see edge data, or even, directly, vertex data (they see their own, interpolated, instance of vertex data.)  If you want the edge angle in some fashion, use GN.  If you want to be able to stop using GN attributes in shader parameters, for export or for performance, output your GN attribute to emission and bake a UV texture.

Comment: @Nathan actually this would be possible if Blender provided partial derivatives `ddx` and `ddy` which take advantage of pixels being run simultaneously in groups and specifically in subgroups of $2×2$ allowing you to compare the normal with 3 neighboring pixels. Maybe in OSL that can be done? BTW, the derivatives are screen-space (hence pixels) so this would be a problem if the other face of an edge would be occluded

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady It would be possible, for the sample that immediately bordered the edge.  And I would be positively delighted if the node editor exposed screen space derivatives, for a lot more reasons than this.  But I don't think that guest is interested in a 2-sample wide map of edge angle in this case-- I think they want the edge angle, interpolated across the face, since that's what a GN attribute in shader nodes will give them.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Note that if they didn't really need it interpolated across the face, just wanted it derived from screen space derivatives, they could use a bevel node in Cycles to acquire this.  Which compares normals via screen space derivatives.  I think.

Comment: When they're smooth there's also no edge…

Comment: @guest GN reads the true edge angle; if we want the angle, at the edge, of the normals of a smooth-shaded mesh, it approaches zero.  I think that there may be some misunderstanding of stuff here.  What I'd recommend is asking a question that focuses on what you've done so far, what you want to achieve, and why what you've done doesn't achieve that.  It's often a better idea to ask about an exact, specific problem rather than something general.

Comment: I just want to use the unsigned angle output as something like the Geometry node's Pointiness output. but useable for EEVEE too.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Comment: I've just changed the title to "How to make an edge mask without ambient occlusion in EEVEE." Maybe this would explain my question better.

Comment: @guest It's still not a great question, and you'll probably not get answers because of that.  I'm sorry.  If you want pointiness in Eevee, ask about that, not "edge mask," which doesn't have any single meaning.  But, don't ask that, because you can just google "pointiness in Eevee" and find a lot of answers on the web.  And if certain categories of answers aren't going to be useful for you, like "no AO", then we want to know *why* that won't work for you, so we don't recommend some answer that doesn't use AO, but still doesn't work for you because it violates the unstated reasons for no AO.

Comment: Also please take a look at other questions on this site (especially high rated questions) to get a better understanding how to ask questions.